# Inserting a value to the new field that I created in Magento database

Tags: php, mysql, magento, newsletter

my question might be lame for magento developers but I am very new to the platform. I added a new input field to my newsletter subscription called offer type as I am encouraging users to subscribe in order to get promo code.

I added the input type hidden in the static page

```
<input placeholder="email: example@example.com" class="email-offer-revealer" name="email" required="" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" spellcheck="false" type="email">
<input name="couponName" value="first offer" type="hidden">
```

in app/code/core/Mage/Newsletter/controllers/SubscriberController.php I added the following line

```
 $offer = (string) $this->getRequest()->getPost('couponName');
 $status = Mage::getModel('newsletter/subscriber')->subscribe($email,$offer);
```

in app/code/core/Mage/Newsletter/Model/Subscriber.php I added the following

```
 public function subscribe($email, $offer){
```

The $offer as new argument to be inserted into the offer field in my newsletter table in the DB.
I've been told that Magento will give me automatic access to getOffer and setOffer so i added the following for the same method

```
$this->setOffer($offer);
```

The problem is i can echo that value, but I can not insert it into the database only i can insert the email what is next?

Thanks

Comment: Have You added new field offer in newsletter_subscriber table

Comment: yes Of course I did, i added a varchar field called offer, that is why I added setOffer and getOffer in the code

Comment: By the way you should never touch the core files, you should rewrite them by extentions or copy them into local/mage/...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you updated some value in model you can try to call save to put the new value into database.

Something like:

$quote->setCouponCode();

$quote->save();

Comment: I will try this out as this is the only option that I did not try yet, thank you anyway

Comment: It works!! Thank you $this->save(); after $this->setOffer($offer); worked like charm